# Business days and hours picker for JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for existing jQuery plugins that can be used as a picker for business days and hours, something that looks similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Haven't seen any. Its easy to built.

Comment: Why don't you use any time picker and let your users pick multiple?

Comment: You will need to build custom. You can pull any calender and use it.
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/best-jquery-date-picker-plugins-for-input-fields

Answer (score 3):

Even its not the exact thing you are looking, check this out

http://gendelf.github.io/jquery.businessHours/

Answer (score 2):

'From' could be drop-down using simple jQuery -ui - same with 'to'

Mon-Sun are just a radio-group where you can only select one -> http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Then you can add these strings together (or convert to date-time if it isn't just for display purposes and format it after)

Finally append to 'results' box using something like

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

So the plug-ins you want are jQuery-ui and some tagging plug-in (of which there are hundreds) - the rest is some simple javascript to tie it all together. Have a go - if you get stuck post again with what you have tried.